# How to modify table to three-lines table in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggpmisc)
library(ggplot2)

data2 <- data.frame(x=rep(1:4,2),
                    y=c(0,1,4,4,0,2,3,2),
                    group=c(rep('a',4),rep('b',4)))



ggplot(data2,aes(x,y,group=group))+
  geom_point(aes(color=group),size=3)+
  geom_line(aes(color=group))+
  annotate(geom = 'table',x=3.6,y=0,
           label = list(data2),
           size=3)
```

How to modify this table to three-lines table within the plotting region of a ggplot?
Thank you.